# Standard page image headers in VF page

Tags: images, header-bar

I want to emulate the header image and text on the standard Task edit page in my VF page. Is there any built-in components to do this, or do I just have to use raw HTML and a static image resource?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why yes there is. The one you are looking for is called 'SectionHeader'. [Here's the doc for it](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_sectionHeader.htm).

Sample Code:

`<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" tabStyle="Opportunity" sidebar="false">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="One of Your Opportunities" subtitle="Exciting !"/>
</apex:page>`